# Vb.net ArgumentNullException when removing from dictionary

Tags: vb.net, dictionary

I'm having an issue where I'm trying to delete an element from my dictionary at the selected index in a listbox. I added 3 elements to a `SortedDictionary` and printing them into a list box. I'm trying to delete the item from the dictionary that is highlighted in the listbox, however when I click remove I get the `System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null. Parameter name: key'` within my Sub `btnDeleteLibrary_Click` Why is this?

Error occurs at the line `Libraries.Remove(lstLibraries.SelectedValue)`

```
Public Class frmManager

    Dim Libraries As New SortedDictionary(Of String, String)

    Private Sub frmManager_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        Libraries.Add("Zahnow Library", "SVSU")
        Libraries.Add("Fleschner Memorial Library", "BR")
        Libraries.Add("Scott D. James Technical Repository", "SDJ")

        lstLibraries.Items.Clear()

        populatelstLibrary()

    End Sub

    Sub populatelstLibrary()
        For Each library In Libraries
            lstLibraries.Items.Add(vbCrLf & library.Key & " --- " & library.Value)
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnDeleteLibrary_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDeleteLibrary.Click

        Libraries.Remove(lstLibraries.SelectedValue)

        lstLibraries.Items.Clear()
        populatelstLibrary()

    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are constructing a custom display string for your ListBox items it makes it harder to map that directly to the dictionary.

The easiest solution would be to create a custom class that you store in the ListBox and set the ListBox's [`DisplayMember`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.displaymember?view=netframework-4.7.2) and [`ValueMember`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.valuemember?view=netframework-4.7.2) properties, telling it how to display each item as well as which property it should get from an item when you call `SelectedValue`.

Class:

```
Public Class LibraryItem

    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Code As String

    Public ReadOnly Property DisplayName As String
        Get
            Return vbCrLf & Me.Name & " --- " & Me.Code
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Sub New()
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(ByVal Name As String, ByVal Code As String)
        Me.Name = Name
        Me.Code = Code
    End Sub
End Class
```

Initial setup:

```
Private Sub frmManager_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    'Tell the ListBox which properties to use for display and value.
    lstLibraries.DisplayMember = "DisplayName"
    lstLibraries.ValueMember = "Name"

    'Your code...
End Sub
```

Filling the ListBox:

```
Sub populatelstLibrary()
    For Each library In Libraries
        lstLibraries.Items.Add(New LibraryItem(library.Key, library.Value))
    Next
End Sub
```

Now `SelectedValue` will get you the value of the selected item's `Name` property, which corresponds to the key in the dictionary.

Comment: That removes the error I was getting, however when clicking the delete button nothing happens, just deselects the item.

Comment: @Devin : I see. That's because you construct a custom string to be displayed in the ListBox, meaning it doesn't correspond to any existing key in the dictionary. Give me a few minutes to update my answer.

Comment: @Devin : Updated!

Comment: Thank you for the help!

Comment: @Devin : Glad I could help! Good luck with your future endeavours!

Answer (score 1):

I would change some things in your code. First it seems that you have your sorted dictionary built with the wrong values for Key and Value, change it to

```
Libraries.Add("SVSU","Zahnow Library")
Libraries.Add("BR", "Fleschner Memorial Library")
Libraries.Add("SDJ", "Scott D. James Technical Repository")
' and  call immediately
populatelstLibrary()
```

Now in populatelstLibrary change the code to

```
Sub populatelstLibrary()
    lstLibraries.DataSource = Nothing
    lstLibraries.DisplayMember = "Value"
    lstLibraries.ValueMember = "Key"
    lstLibraries.DataSource = Libraries.ToList()
End Sub
```

finally in the button click just check for null and remove the SelectedValue

```
Private Sub btnDeleteLibrary_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDeleteLibrary.Click
    If lstLibraries.SelectedValue IsNot Nothing Then
        Libraries.Remove(lstLibraries.SelectedValue)
        populatelstLibrary()
    End If
End Sub
```